# window.openで開いた新規ウィンドウでlocalstorageを登録、削除したい

Tags: javascript

javascriptで以下のようなコードで、新規ウィンドウの状態（オープン時、クローズ時）によって、localstorageに登録、削除を行いたいのですが、新規ウィンドウ側にキー値が登録されません。新規ウィンドウ（オリジンは親ウィンドウと異なります）のlocalstorageに情報登録を行うためにはどのようにすればよいでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
info = 'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=yes,status=no,menubar=no,' +
   'scrollbars=yes,left=0,top=0,resizable=yes,width=1500,height=900,title=no';
var window1 = window.open("http://simmac.local:8082","test00001アクセス",info);
window1.moveTo(0, 0);

window1.addEventListener('load', function(event){
     window1.localStorage.setItem('test00001', 'hogehoge');
     event.returnValue = 'Check';
});
window1.addEventListener('unload', function(event){
     window1.localStorage.removeItem('test00001');
     event.returnValue = 'Check';
});

</script>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 新規ウィンドウのオリジンが異なると言いましたが、具体的には、simmac.local:8081(呼び出し元)→simmac.local:8082(localstorage設定先)です。異なるオリジンでストレージが共有できないことは認識しており、やりたいことは呼び出し先でlocalstorageの値設定、削除が行いたいです。

Comment: cubic さん> 勝手に html,head タグを追加して質問を書き直したようですが、やり過ぎだと思いますけど。body タグが変だし。

Comment: sim さん> ポップブロックに引っ掛かって動かないということはないですか？

Comment: @WebSurfer さん　ありがとうございます。確認をしてみます！

Comment: @WebSurfer 私の編集ではあくまでコードブロックのバッククォート3つ で囲っただけで、タグを勝手に追記したわけではありません。[履歴#1のソース](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/05fbd47c-6eb0-4478-8ff9-77dfed70c3a6/view-source) を見てもらえば分かりますが元々の投稿に含まれていたものです。 / Markdown だけでなく、[一部の HTML](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3499/3060) は直接記載することができるので、適切にインデントやコードブロックでハイライトされていないと不可視な状態になることがあります。

Comment: cubick さん> 上の「編集日時: x時間前」をクリックすると表示される画面からは html,head タグを追加して質問を書き直したと見えます・・・が、それが「バッククォート3つ で囲っただけ」の結果ということでしたら失礼しました。

Comment: 確認をしてみましたが、ブラウザのポップアップはすでに許可されていました。オリジンのsimmac.local:8081,simmac.local:8082は登録されているものの、あえて全許可にもしてみましたがうまく動作しませんでした。。localstorageは諦めてcoｋokieをつかってみようと思います。ありがとうございました。